# Select an input element using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, click

[Inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IuNIM.png)

Im trying to click on this button to move to the login page. 
my code is :

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://moodle.tau.ac.il/')
```

thats work fine but i can only find the form by using

```
loginform = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//form[@id='login']/")
```

I don't know how to get to the button, it's very basic stuff but I didn't find any good example.

Comment: Why can't you just extend your xpath expression to select the input? i.e. `//form[@id="login"]/div/input`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will click on the login button on moodle.tau.ac.il page. 
The line `driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='login']/div/input").click()` finds the login button on the page and clicks it. Xpath is just a selector type that you can use with selenium to find web elements on a page. You can also use ID, classname, and CSSselectors.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = new webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('moodle.tau.ac.il')
# This will take you to the login page.
driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='login']/div/input").click()

# Fills out the login page
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")
elem.send_keys('Your Username')
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/input")
elem.send_keys('Your ID Number')
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")
elem.send_keys('Your Password')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/input").click()
```

Comment: Your way doesnt work, it doesnt able to locate the  elements

Answer (score 2):

The page has two identical login forms and your XPath returns the hidden one.
So with the visible one:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(r"http://moodle.tau.ac.il/")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#page-content #login input[type=submit]").click()
```

Or with an XPath:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(r"http://moodle.tau.ac.il/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("id('page-content')//form[@id='login']//input[@type='submit']").click()
```

Answer (score -1):

You could find it using XPath as mentioned by @ChrisP

You could find it by CSS selector: "#login input[type='text']"

Or you could also just submit the form... loginForm.submit()

Ideally, you'd have a unique id for that button which would make it very easy to find.